# Autofac dependencyResolutionException error

Tags: c#, xamarin, autofac

```
        public static IContainer Container;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TheTheme.SetTheme();
            CultureInfo greekCulture = new CultureInfo("el-GR");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = greekCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = greekCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = greekCulture;
            VersionTracking.Track();
            AppHelper.LoadCfgSettings();
            var e = DependencyService.Get<IEnvironment>();
            var tid = e.GetAndroidSerial();
            AppHelper.WriteSetting(AppHelper.TidKey, tid);
            //class used for registration
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            //scan and register all classes in the assembly
            var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf();
            Container = builder.Build();
            BindingContext = Container.Resolve<AppViewModel>();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
```

Hello. The code above is the App() class and I am getting the error below:
**Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException:** 'An exception was thrown while activating Argos.AppViewModel -> Argos.Networking.NetworkService.'
The code bellow is the AppViewModel constractor.
The code worked and without changing anything it stopped.

```
 public AppViewModel(IMessageServices messageServices ,IDialogMessage dialogMessage, INetworkService networkService, INavigationService navigationService, IAppDownloader appDownloader)
        {
            _messageServices = messageServices;
            _messageServices.CreateHubConnection();
            _dialogMessage = dialogMessage;
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _appDownloader = appDownloader;
            _networkService = networkService;
            _wakeUp = DependencyService.Get<IWakeUp>();
            _deviceManipulation = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceManipulation>();
            _messageServices.OnMessageReceived += _messageServices_OnMessageReceived;
            _messageServices.OnUrlLinkReceived += _messageServices_OnUrlLinkReceived;
            _messageServices.OnBlockReceived += _messageServices_OnBlockReceived;
            _messageServices.OnCommandReceived += _messageServices_OnCommandReceived;

            MessageList = new ObservableRangeCollection<MessageModel>();


        }
```

Comment: I can't see where you have registered `INetworkService` in the DI container

Comment: From the Assembly.
```var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf();
```

Comment: I'm really not a fan of that way of adding dependencies, especially as this code you have here will add every single type in your application which is a huge waste. Personally, I prefer to have more control over it. Are the `NetworkService` and `INetworkService` types in the same project then or are they perhaps in another?

Comment: Same project, same namespace.
I tried manually to register it like that:
`builder.RegisterType<NetworkService>().As<INetworkService>();`
but nothing.

Comment: If AppViewModel has an empty constractor then it steps over.

`public AppViewModel(){ }`

Comment: Read - and post - the WHOLE exception message. Also, update code to be a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - all the event wire-up code, anything that doesn't play in reproducing this - remove it, but make sure it's still real, working code. That will also help you narrow down where the error is.